# Prolog print in the specific format

Tags: prolog

Say I have two lists `[A, B, C]` and `[D, E, F]` on my hand now.
The values in list1 and list2 are in the same range, but I don't exactly know how they match with each other.

There is one possibility that `A = D = 1, B = E = 2, C = F = 3`.

Based on the condition above, how can I print the result in the following format???

```
(ONE, A, D)

(TWO, B, E)

(THREE, C, F)
```

The original problem is, you have to figure out the value of each variable in list1 and list2 under the given constraints. The constraints are as following:

```
A < B, B < C, D < E, E < F, 
the range of [A, B, C] is from 1 to 3, 
the range of [D, E, F] is from 1 to 3, 
[A, B, C] are all different numbers, 
[D, E, F] are all different numbers.
```

So far I write something like:

```
calculate([A, B, C, D, E, F]) :-
    between(1, 3, A),
    between(1, 3, B),
    between(1, 3, C),
    between(1, 3, D),
    between(1, 3, E),
    between(1, 3, F),
    A < B, B < C, D < E, E < F.
```

After I consult this code file and call `calculate([A, B, C, D, E, F])`, I get the final result `A = D = 1, B = E = 2, C = F = 3`, but how can I print in an elegant format???

Comment: This is not clear. Names starting with upper case are normally variables in Prolog. Do you want to print the variable names or the values? Are the values in each list unique? Generally, you want to first collect the matching values, and then print (two loops).

Comment: This isn't clear at all. What are the inputs? At least show the query you want to make in Prolog and some attempts you've made to solve it. Some specific examples would help clarify as well.

Comment: @lurker Please check my new edit.

Comment: @TomasBy Please check my new edit.

Comment: @TomasBy But I want to output the result based on the calculation, I can't fix my code to be ```write('A = '), write(A)```

Comment: *How can I print in an elegant format???* Please define what you mean by "elegant format". Do you mean, given your example, you literally want to see, `(ONE, 1, 1)` and `(TWO, 2, 2)` and `(THREE, 3, 3)`? That seems to be what you've asked if I put all this together. But that doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
printnicely([A,B,C],[D,E,F]) :-
  count(A,'A',mapping([],[],[]),M0), count(B,'B',M0,M1), count(C,'C',M1,M2),
  count(D,'D',M2,M3), count(E,'E',M3,M4), count(F,'F',M4,M),
  printmapping(M).

count(1,Name,mapping(Ones,Twos,Threes),mapping([Name|Ones],Twos,Threes)).
count(2,Name,mapping(Ones,Twos,Threes),mapping(Ones,[Name|Twos],Threes)).
count(3,Name,mapping(Ones,Twos,Threes),mapping(Ones,Twos,[Name|Threes])).

printmapping(mapping(Ones,Twos,Threes)) :-
  reverse(Ones,RevOnes), reverse(Twos,RevTwos), reverse(Threes,RevThrees),
  write('ONE '),write(RevOnes),nl,
  write('TWO '),write(RevTwos),nl,
  write('THREE '),write(RevThrees),nl.
```

Produces:

```
| ?- calculate([A,B,C],[D,E,F]), printnicely([A,B,C],[D,E,F]).
ONE [A,D]
TWO [B,E]
THREE [C,F]
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can solve your problem.

```
number(1,'ONE').
number(2,'TWO').
number(3,'THREE').

position(1,'L1','A').
position(2,'L1','B').
position(3,'L1','C').

position(1,'L2','D').
position(2,'L2','E').
position(3,'L2','F').

find(Curr,Max):-
    Curr > Max.

find(Curr,Max):-
    Curr =< Max,
    number(Curr,V),
    position(Curr,'L1',A),
    position(Curr,'L2',B),
    write('('),
    write((V,A,B)),
    write(')'), 
    nl,
    C is Curr+1,
    find(C,Max).

?- find(1,3).
(ONE,A,D)
(TWO,B,E)
(THREE,C,F)
```

First you have to define some predicates (in this case `number/2`) to match the number with its word. Then you have to define a predicate (`position/2`) to link the position of the element with the associated letter. Then you can traverse all the list with `find/2`. BTW this solution is not modular at all...

Answer (score -1):

This is the best!

```
    ?- writeln('(ONE,A,D)'),writeln('(TWO,B,E)'),writeln('(THREE,C,F)').
    (ONE,A,D)
    (TWO,B,E)
    (THREE,C,F)
    true.
```

Comment: What I mean here is that I don't know exactly A = D and B = E and C = F. I just have 2 lists on my hand, then I want to match the same values in list1 & list2, print them out in the specific format.